# convert mongo shell query to spring data

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a mongoshell query like the below

```
db.viewedProfile.aggregate(

  {$match : { "viewedMemberId":  "54d6dd15e4b0611ba5762e3d" }},
  {$group : { _id: null,
         total: {$sum: "$count"}}})
```

I am struggling with converting this to spring data mongodb.  I am using spring data version 1.4.3.RELEASE.  the aggregation constructor seems to not recognize the match method.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. "Convert this code" questions without any attemp shown are not really encouraged. If you that some effort has been made then you are more likely to receive some guidance. There is an [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31766404/edit) link on your question for you to make changes with.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;

...

Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
    ViewedProfile.class,
    match(Criteria.where("viewedMemberId").is("54d6dd15e4b0611ba5762e3d")),
    group().sum("count").as("total")
);
```